# Compare two file paths in NSStrings including links

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsstring, filepath

I am solving a bug caused by path comparison using `-[NSString isEqualToString:]`

```
(lldb) po aString
/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/DE14BC26-B07D-46C2-89BF-E800231BAD1F/a.app/b.bundle/epub/OEBPS/Text/02.xhtml

(lldb) po bString
/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/DE14BC26-B07D-46C2-89BF-E800231BAD1F/a.app/b.bundle/epub/OEBPS/Text/02.xhtml
```

`[aString isEqualToString:bString]` would yield `NO`.

But since /var is a symlink to /private/var, they are referring to the same file. May I know the correct way to fix this?

Comment: One starts with `/private/var` and the other is `/var`, it's not the same even by looking

Comment: var is symlink to private/var

Comment: I know, but remember they are `NSString` objects, so they were compared as strings and as objects they were not the same.

Comment: I added an answer to resolve the symlink from `NSString`.

Comment: I found a very good article related to NSURL file comparison: https://digitalleaves.com/blog/2013/09/nsurl-files-equality-comparison-and-equivalency/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using:

```
NSString *resolvedPath = [path stringByResolvingSymlinksInPath];
```

then compare. See [NSString Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/).

For `NSURL` equalvent, use:

```
NSURL *resolvedURL = [url URLByResolvingSymlinksInPath];
```

See [NSURL Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURL/URLByResolvingSymlinksInPath).

Comment: How about if they are of NSURL?

Comment: Then you use `URLByResolvingSymlinksInPath` of `NSURL`. Or convert `NSURL` to `NSString` path before the comparison.

Comment: I found what I need in this category file: https://github.com/DigitalLeaves/NSURLEquality/blob/master/NSURLTest/NSURL%2BRealEquality.m